# Referencing Hidden Item in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, hidden

So I have a select list and a hidden page item, I want to dynamically update the select list based on the value of the hidden item.

My select list code is the following:

```
if :P26_HIDDEN_ITEM != 'Other'
then
return
q'[SELECT DISTINCT tag d, tag r 
FROM builds
WHERE instr(tag,:p26_env_storage)>0
OR tag = 'tagged']';
else
return
q'[SELECT DISTINCT tag d, tag r 
FROM builds
WHERE tag = 'tagged']';
```

Now I believe there is no problem with my code, when I make the hidden item any other form of page item  or even reference another page item such as a select list the query runs as expected, but when :P26_HIDDEN_ITEM is hidden the query just runs the else statement ignoring the top half of the query.

The problem is the same if I change the conditional too, it always goes straight to the else statement. Also I know for a fact that :P26_HIDDEN_ITEM updates as I have checked it multiple times in the session.

So is there a way to reference a hidden item like this or do I need to take a different route?

I'm using APEX 4.2.2 if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the same effect with a simple query-based LOV:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag d, tag r 
FROM builds
WHERE (:P26_HIDDEN_ITEM != 'Other'
  AND (instr(tag,:p26_env_storage)>0 OR tag = 'tagged')
OR (NVL(:P26_HIDDEN_ITEM,'Other') = 'Other'
  AND tag = 'tagged');
```

Make sure that `P26_HIDDEN_ITEM,P26_ENV_STORAGE` are listed in the **Cascading LOV Parent Item(s)**.